# Core Data - NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "VisitsModel", in: AppDelegate.stack.context) returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an Entity called "VisitsModel" which has no attributes and a single relationship (one-to-many) to another entity "Visit"

I am not using the "class Definition" and manually writing the classes.

However, when I execute this line below, it returns nil.

if let ent = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "VisitsModel", in: AppDelegate.stack.context)

My class looks like this
class VisitsModel: NSManagedObject, Mappable {

```
@NSManaged public var visits: NSSet?
```

Any thoughts.?

Comment: I usually get the `managedObjectContext` like this  `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate` `let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext` ...  maybe your `AppDelegate.stack.context` is nil?

Comment: I checked to make sure it is not nil.

Comment: does the app crash?

Comment: No. It does not crash as I am checking for nil and just showing an error.

Comment: Did you create your `NSManagedObjectModel`? Did you assign an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to your context?